# how to launch activity setting only one onclicklistener

Tags: android, performance

So i have this code and i want to avoid setting the onclicklistener method for every button i have . 
is there a way to avoid doing that ??

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent jus = new Intent (Home.this,jus.class);
            startActivity(jus);
        }

    });
    sweets.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent sweets = new Intent (Home.this,sweets.class);
            startActivity(sweets);
        }

    });
    patisserie.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent patisserie = new Intent (Home.this,patisserie.class);
            startActivity(patisserie);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

Your Activity must `implements OnClickListener`

Inside `OnCreate()`

```
    sweets.setOnClickListener(this); 
    patisserie.setOnClickListener(this);
```

then after `OnCreate()`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) { 

    switch(v.getId()){
       case R.id.sweetsbuttonid:
         // do stuff related sweets click
         break;
       case R.id.patisseriebuttonid:
         // do stuff related patisserie click
         break;
     }

}
```

Comment: @AbdelhadiKhiati what refusing?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class that implements OnClickListener that you can accept a Intent parameter to with pre-set activity. THat way the parameter activity will be started but the listeners will all be instances of the same parent. No need to re-write code.